# Node.js .forEach output not as expected in Raspbian but fine in windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, foreach, raspbian

The code is identical across platforms but when running my code in windows it performs as expected and returns:

```
test: US
test: us
```

But then running it in Raspbian which is the only change, it returns:

```
test:
US
us
```

I couldn't find any reason why it would behave differently in Raspbian or even just base Linux which is why I am asking here. The code I am used to create these outputs is as follows:

```
var data = fs.readFileSync('./txt/wordlist.txt', 'ascii').toString().split("\r\n"); 

var filtered = data.filter(function (el) {
  return el != "";
});
        
if(filtered!=""){
  filtered.forEach(function(d){
    var dFS = "test: " + d;
    console.log(dFS);
  });
}
```

The wordlist I have is as follows with plans to expand of course:

```
US
us
```

The method used to create the wordlist for completeness:

```
added.forEach(function(a){
          fs.appendFileSync('./txt/wordlist.txt',`\r\n${a}`,'ascii');
        });
```

Comment: Have you tried running a sample `forloop` with mock data?  It is very strange if it behaves like this on raspbian

Comment: so I just tried that and it worked the same on both so I wonder what the issue is hmm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turned out to be a strange format issue in regards to my wordlist both being written to in ascii and read in ascii including using \r\n when writing and splitting the returned output. I realised this was a main different in Linux environments and after changing everything to utf-8 and splitting on only \n and replacing the line breaks in the wordlist it worked as expected.

Comment: Alternatively you can support both Unix (Linux, MacOS) and Windows file formats by using a regular expression to split on: `.split(/\r?\n/)`

Comment: Oh that is an amazing suggestion thank you (: how would this apply when writing to the file?

Comment: I personally would only write files with `\n` unless you need to open it in notepad.exe on Windows 7 or Windows 8. Newer versions of notepad knows what to do with unix line endings. However if you really need to know what the normal line ending is for your current OS there is a variable for that: `os = require('os'); os.EOL`